# I can't run Tensorboard in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tensorboard

A couple of days ago I ran Tensorboard in Ubuntu and I got results without any problem.

I used a pre-trained model and I want to put the results into Tensorboard. From models / object_detection folder, I run the command:

```
tensorboard --bind_all --port 6006 --logdir=’training’
```

and I got the response:

```
tensorboard is active on ip and port TensorBoard 2.0.2 at http://ubuntu:6006/ (Press CTRL+C to quit).
```

So I went on the web and took my results graphs etc.

Today, I did the same but I got the above errors:

```
TensorBoard 2.0.2 at http://ubuntu:6006/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/tensorboard", line 8, in <module>
sys.exit(run_main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 66, in run_main
app.run(tensorboard.main, flags_parser=tensorboard.configure)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
_run_main(main, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
sys.exit(main(argv))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorboard/program.py", line 267, in main
return runner(self.flags) or 0
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorboard/program.py", line 283, in 
_run_serve_subcommand
self._register_info(server)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorboard/program.py", line 329, in _register_info
manager.write_info_file(info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorboard/manager.py", line 267, in write_info_file
payload = "%s\n" % _info_to_string(tensorboard_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorboard/manager.py", line 126, in _info_to_string
for k in _TENSORBOARD_INFO_FIELDS
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorboard/manager.py", line 126, in <dictcomp>
for k in _TENSORBOARD_INFO_FIELDS
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Please is there any help?

Answer (score 0):

caused by the default encoding difference between python 2.7 (ascii) and 3.x (utf-8). I install python 3.5 and it's gone.